# How to crop/clip in OpenGL using u_transformation

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to crop / clip a shader using "u_transformation" in OpenGL. Specifically, I want to keep only half of the top part. Viewport should not be changed. I have tried the following code, it does something but the result is strange and not what I'm expecting:

```
gfloat left = -1.0f;
gfloat right = 1.0f;
gfloat bottom = 0.0f;//-1.0f gives the identity matrix and I see everything
gfloat top = 1.0f;
gfloat far = 1.0f;
gfloat near = -1.0f;

gfloat r_l = right - left;
gfloat t_b = top - bottom;
gfloat f_n = far - near;
gfloat tx = - (right + left) / (right - left);
gfloat ty = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
gfloat tz = - (far + near) / (far - near);

gfloat orthographicMatrix[16];
orthographicMatrix[0] = 2.0f / r_l;
orthographicMatrix[1] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[2] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[3] = tx;

orthographicMatrix[4] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[5] = 2.0f / t_b;
orthographicMatrix[6] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[7] = ty;

orthographicMatrix[8] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[9] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[10] = 2.0f / f_n;
orthographicMatrix[11] = tz;

orthographicMatrix[12] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[13] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[14] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[15] = 1.0f;

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program_handle, "u_transformation"), 1, FALSE, orthographicMatrix);
```

How should I setup my orthographic matrix?

**EDIT 1**
Here is a picture of what I have, what I get and what I want.
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL expects matrices to be stored in column major order. So the translation vector goes into matrix elements 12, 13, and 14:

```
orthographicMatrix[0] = 2.0f / r_l;
orthographicMatrix[1] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[2] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[3] = 0.0f;

orthographicMatrix[4] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[5] = 2.0f / t_b;
orthographicMatrix[6] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[7] = 0.0f;

orthographicMatrix[8] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[9] = 0.0f;
orthographicMatrix[10] = 2.0f / f_n;
orthographicMatrix[11] = 0.0f;

orthographicMatrix[12] = tx;
orthographicMatrix[13] = ty;
orthographicMatrix[14] = tz;
orthographicMatrix[15] = 1.0f;
```

This is under the assumption that you're multiplying vectors with matrices from the left in your GLSL code, for example:

```
gl_Position = u_transformation * inPosition;
```

Another problem is in how you set the `bottom` value:

```
gfloat bottom = 0.0f;//-1.0f gives the identity matrix and I see everything
gfloat top = 1.0f;
```

You seem to assume that these values specify the range of the window that your letter is mapped to. The way the matrix is calculated, that's not the case. These values specify the range of input coordinates that is mapped to the size of the window.

In your example, it looks like you're using a coordinate range of [-1.0, 1.0] for drawing your letters. With the identity matrix, this maps directly to OpenGL normalized device coordinates, which also have a range of [-1.0, 1.0], which makes the letter map to the whole window.

Now if you use 0.0 for `bottom`, this means that you're mapping the input coordinate range of [0.0, 1.0] to the window size, which is the top half of your letter.

To make the letter fill only half the window, you need to map a **larger** range of coordinates to the window size. Following your sketch, the range should be [-3.0, 1.0]. With this, the middle of the range is -1.0, meaning that the bottom of the letter, which has a y-coordinate of -1.0, maps to the middle of the window.

Base on this, you should set the values as:

```
gfloat bottom = -3.0f;
gfloat top = 1.0f;
```

Comment: This is correct for the column major order. Also, I had to put 0.5f for orthographicMatrix[5] and not 2.0f to get a vertical crop (similar to a zoom-in).

Comment: @gregoiregentil I added a second part to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense with my finding that I should get orthografhicMatrix[5]=0.5f. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Set
orthographicMatrix[10] = -2.0f / f_n;

You can get detailed information about calculation projection matrix. http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html#ortho

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you included at least a paraphrase of the relevant information from this link in your answer, or otherwise explained why this is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your attention Paul.

Comment: No problem, though I suggest actually writing out how it works. [Link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) are not ideal for a number of reasons, not the least of which is the possibility of link rot.

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working. Perhaps I had far and near inverted... But in any case, orthographicMatrix[10] = 1.0f; like for the identity matrix. See the edit to explain precisely what I want to do.